# C++ syntax explanation

Tags: c++

I have a following inline function:

```
inline void normalizeGrayOutputCentredSigmoide(const type meanValue=(type)0.0, const type sensitivity=(type)2.0, const type maxOutputValue=(type)255.0)
{
    normalizeGrayOutputCentredSigmoide(meanValue, sensitivity, 255.0, this->Buffer(), this->Buffer(), this->getNBpixels()), maxOutputValue;
};
```

At this line the following compiler warning appears:

```
warning: right-hand operand of comma has no effect
```

Can anybody describe what this kind written function supposed to do?

What does comma operator mean in this case?

Comment: you close your method before last parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`maxOutputValue` is outside of your function parameters. The compiler thus handles it as being the right operand of a [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), which in this case is not effective. See the linked wikipedia page for details.

Answer (score 1):

You closed your parenthesis before `maxOutputValue`, so the compiler interprets it as  a function and a "useless" value after it, which is what the error is saying